# Mounting a Linux share with a single account on RDS for all users

Tags: remote-desktop, network-shares, windows-server, shared-access

I have this situation:

- a Linux server (CentOS 7) providing access to some of its files through `samba`
- This server is not currently joined to the Windows domain and cannot be for practical reasons
- a Windows Server 2016 with RDS

The problem:

- I want to mount a share on the Linux server from the Windows RDS server, and have it available to all users starting sessions on the RDS
- I don't want to have to manage credentials for all the users on the server, nor do I want the credentials for some service account to be available to all users (as I need to avoid them mounting the same storage from elsewhere)

In the past, I could have set up a GPO with cached credentials to mount the network share and map a drive accessible to all users, but that's no longer possible.

What is the best way to get this done, given that the very best solution (join the server to the domain) or the easiest solution (create credentials for just this purpose and put them in a logon script) are not available?

How can I keep the credentials out of the hands of users, while still allowing all users access to the share on a drive letter?

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: I assumed that was clear from the way the question was phrased: I've considered adding a logon script, but don't see a way that won't make the credentials available to other users; I've considered adding a service account specifically for providing access to the share, but that would still make it public and allow access from elsewhere; I know that a GPO would have ben the approach previously - but that option has been disabled and it's not clear what the expected alternative is there. Hence the question: this seems non-trivial to me. Adding to the domain and mounting directly is not an option